# SensorManager nullptr even after initialization Windows Sensor API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sensors

I am trying to get sensor data by following the Windows Sensor API example.

Code is straightforward:

```
int main() {
   printf("Starting SensorManager...\n");

   HRESULT hr = S_OK;

   // Sensor interface pointers
   ISensorManager* pSensorManager = NULL;
   ISensorCollection* pSensorColl = NULL;

   // Create the sensor manager.
   hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SensorManager,
       NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
       IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSensorManager));

   if (pSensorManager == nullptr) {
       printf("no sensor manager");
   }

   if (hr == HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_ACCESS_DISABLED_BY_POLICY))
   {
       // Unable to retrieve sensor manager due to 
       // group policy settings. Alert the user.
       printf("Failed getting sensor manager due to disabled policy...\n");
   }

   hr = pSensorManager->GetSensorsByType(SENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER_3D, &pSensorColl);
   return 0;
}
```

`CoCreateInstance` should return a `ISensorManager` pointer, which will be used to access and retrieve the sensors.

My problem with this code is that `pSensorManager` does not get initiailized, even after `CoCreateInstance()`. I check if it is `nullptr` after and indeed it prints out the error message. This code is straight from Microsoft's website so I cannot figure out why `SensorManager` would be null.

I am using 1) `Windows SDK 10` 2) `Windows Kits 10.0.17763` 3) `Visual Studio 2013.` I have properly included all the header files, so I can build the code.

Why would `CoCreateInstance()` not initialize `pSensorManager`? Whether the sensor device is connected or not, shouldn't it initialize it properly?

Comment: you not call `CoInitialize[Ex]` and `HRESULT` from `CoCreateInstance` sure say you about this. guess you got `CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED` - *CoInitialize has not been called.*

Comment: What do you mean by that? Could you please provide a link if I am missing something?

Comment: simply look for error returned by `CoCreateInstance` to you

Comment: Oh my, I was missing something humongous. This is my first time using COM. Thank you so much.